# Distributivity property for smooth parabolic induction

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a local field $k$ of characteristic zero with maximal split torus $T$, Weyl group $W$, Borel $ B$ and a parabolic subgroup $P$ such that $P\supset B \supset T$. Denote by $i_P^G=\mathrm{Ind}_P^G(\mathbf{1})$ the smooth parabolic induction of the trivial representation. In Borel & Wallachs's "Continous Cohomology, Discrete subgroups, and Representations of Reductive Groups" it is stated in Lemma 4.5 of chapter $X$ that for $V_0,\ldots, V_m$ $G$-submodules of $V:=i_P^G$
$$ V_0 \cap (V_1+ \ldots V_m)=(V_0 \cap V_1) + \ldots + (V_0 \cap V_m)$$
holds (in the book it is in a litte more general version, but for understanding the proof it should be enough).

They state first that the equality holds obviously for $V_N$-modules (Jaquet module of V). **Why??**

Because the RHS is trivially contained in the LHS, the equation follows by some observations of section 3.2 in the same chapter, which are the following:

For an unramified character $\chi$ of $G$ they denote by $PS(\chi)$ the space $\mathrm{Ind}_P^G(\mathbb{C}_\phi)$ where $P$ acts $\mathbb{C}_\phi$ by $\phi=\chi\delta^{1/2}$ and $\delta$ being the modular function on $P$. Then

1. The semi-simplification of $PS(\chi)_N$ as an $T$-module is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{s \in W}\mathbb{C}_{\delta^{1/2}\cdot s\chi}$.
2. $PS(\chi)$ has a finite Jordan-Höder series.
3. If $\chi' \notin W(\chi)$ then $PS(\chi)$ and $PS(\chi')$ have no constituent in common
4. If $s\chi \neq \chi$ for $s \neq 1, s \in W$, then $PS(\chi)$ has a unique non-zero irreducible sub representation, which is denoted by $W_\chi$.

Then by 4.

5. If $s\chi \neq \chi$ for $s \neq 1, s \in W$,then $PS(\chi)$ has a multiplicity free Jordan-Holder series and each constituent is equivalent to some $W_{s\chi}$.
6. An irreducible, admissible module $V$ is a constituent (resp. submodule) of some $PS(\chi)$ if and only if $V^B \neq (0)$.

But at the moment I am more or less unable to make a link from the observations to the equality above.